# How to add a default value to an already existing column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, alter-table, default-constraint

I have an existing column in my SQL Server database. I have tried about everything I can think of but can not get a default value to be added to the column. What works in every other database is

```
alter table mytable 
  alter column mycolumn set default(now()) --mycolumn is a datetime
```

How do I do this in SQL Server?

The error I get for that exact syntax is `incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'`

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT def_mycolumn DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR mycolumn
```

For more info, see: [Working with Default Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175912%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Comment: @Earlz: Saw that, most appreciated :)

Comment: Methinks `SYSUTCDATETIME()` would be a better default expression, as `GETDATE()` returns the time in the server's local timezone which is silly.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to change the default value of an already existing column. You need to first drop the constraint and then add the constraint all over again as below

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLE> 
DROP CONSTRAINT <CONSTRAINT NAME>

ALTER TABLE <TABLE> 
ADD CONSTRAINT <CONSTRAINT NAME> DEFAULT <VALUE> for <COLUMN>
```

If you are not having the Constraint details of the table, you can use the below query

```
sp_helpconstraint <TABLE>
```